# Clone JSON object that fits in multiple categories and group by those categories

Tags: javascript, json

I have some javascript that I found that allows me to group JSON objects by some property. It works great but I need to be able to clone the objects that are in multiple categories and group them by those categories/properties. For example:

```
 var products = [{"Name": "Product 1", 
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 1",
  "Cost": 100,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Laptop, Tablet", 
"ID":0
},
{"Name":"Product 2",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 2",
  "Cost": 120,
  "Function": "Healthcare",
  "Type": "Laptop, Tablet", 
"ID":1
},
{"Name": "Product 3",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 3",
  "Cost": 130,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Desktop", 
"ID":2
}];
```

Should become

```
[{"Name": "Product 1", 
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 1",
  "Cost": 100,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Laptop", 
"ID":0
},
{"Name":"Product 2",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 2",
  "Cost": 120,
  "Function": "Healthcare",
  "Type": "Laptop", 
"ID":1
}],
[{"Name": "Product 1", 
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 1",
  "Cost": 100,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Tablet", 
"ID":0
},
{"Name":"Product 2",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 2",
  "Cost": 120,
  "Function": "Healthcare",
  "Type": "Tablet", 
"ID":1
}],
[{"Name": "Product 3",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 3",
  "Cost": 130,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Desktop", 
"ID":2
}]
```

This is my code so far:

```
 function LoadDevicesByType(){
    var result = groupBy(products, function(item)
    {
      return [item.Type];
    });
    return result;  
  }

  function groupBy( array , f )
  {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach( function( o )
    {
      var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
      groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
      groups[group].push( o );  
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
    {
      return groups[group]; 
    })
  }
```

Any idea how I achieve this? Right now I am just grouping by the Type property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split over the `Type` string and copy the outer object:

```js
const input = [{"Name": "Product 1", 
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 1",
  "Cost": 100,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Laptop, Tablet", 
"ID":0
},
{"Name":"Product 2",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 2",
  "Cost": 120,
  "Function": "Healthcare",
  "Type": "Laptop, Tablet", 
"ID":1
},
{"Name": "Product 3",
  "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 3",
  "Cost": 130,
  "Function": "Engineering",
  "Type": "Desktop", 
"ID":2
}];

const separatedByTypeObj = {};
input.forEach(product => {
  product.Type.split(', ').forEach(type => {
    const newProduct = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
    newProduct.Type = type;
    if (!separatedByTypeObj[type]) separatedByTypeObj[type] = [];
    separatedByTypeObj[type].push(newProduct)
  });
});
const separatedByTypeArr = Object.values(separatedByTypeObj);
console.log(separatedByTypeArr);
```

(it would be more elegant to use `.reduce`, but if you're new to array methods, `forEach` is probably easier to understand)

Comment: This groups them within the json but it doesnt separate them into different arrays.

Comment: Oh, your "Should become" is missing a `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end so I didn't realize the arrays were intended to be part of a larger array. Tweak is simple, just add each `type` to an object and then use that object's `values`, as in answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var products = [{
        "Name": "Product 1",
        "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 1",
        "Cost": 100,
        "Function": "Engineering",
        "Type": "Laptop, Tablet",
        "ID": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Product 2",
        "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 2",
        "Cost": 120,
        "Function": "Healthcare",
        "Type": "Laptop, Tablet",
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "Product 3",
        "Details": "Lorum Ipsum lorum ipsum 3",
        "Cost": 130,
        "Function": "Engineering",
        "Type": "Desktop",
        "ID": 2
    }
];

function modifiedOutput() {
    const output = [];
    products.forEach(x => {
        x.Type.split(",").forEach(t => {
            const itemType = t.trim();
            const newX = Object.assign({}, x, {
                Type: itemType
            });
            output.push(newX);
        });
    });

    console.log(output);
    return output;
}

const output = modifiedOutput();
```

https://codepen.io/zoom2ashish/pen/RMMErN